# CLR assembly loading

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-loading

I've been reading about and experimenting with assemblies when trying to debug some project loading issues. I'd like to clarify some questions regarding assembly loading.

I was testing Common.Logging library with two projects - App and Library. App used 2.1 version whilst Library used 1.2. App was able to run and load Library just fine and I observed that it loaded 2.1 version by inspecting AppDomain events. The inverse situation when App referenced 1.2 and Library referenced 2.1 caused a file load exception in runtime.

My question is, why was the assembly loaded in the first case? I'd expect an exception just like the one from the second scenario. What if 2.1 version wasn't backwards compatible? Is it something that's entirely up to authors to always preserve or can they somehow specify that 2.1 can't be used when 1.2 is required?

Comment: "What if"? You can easily create your own experiments and see what kind of exceptions it would throw. As incompatibility varies, different kinds of exceptions should appear.

Comment: @LexLi
It was a rhetorical question. I'm more interested in why it's allowed in the first place and if there is any way to change the loading logic as an assembly author.

Comment: "Why" is not a question Stack Overflow can answer. You might post to Microsoft's CoreCLR repo on GitHub to see if an answer can be given. My personal opinion is that such a design is the simplest.

Comment: @LexLi 
I've considered GH but in my experience it's the opposite and GH is usually used for bug reports and suggestions, not questions. If you have any idea where I could find the answer or how it can be looked up, I'd appreciate a link or a hint. I've looked through MSDN and checked CLA via C#, which is almost always a reliable source, but haven't found a direct specification or explanation.